# What boot manager is this?

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

No doubt you have stumbled across the Black Dwarf NAS, but your man also has this:

http://www.willudesign.com/osxboxproTop.html

[image]

This image shows the boot manager, I can't see anywhere in the article where he mentions what software this is.

Does anyone know what software he uses and if his image is a custom splash screen?

I've emailed him, with no response, hence I'm asking here :-)

Comment: You should really simply post the image you are referring to.  Digging through a site like this is at a minimum, a hassle, and border-line spam the way you have presented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boot menu is displayed by an [EFi-X](http://gizmodo.com/5049756/review-efix-dongle-perfectly-transforms-pc-to-mac) dongle, which is mentioned to be used for booting in that page.

> It was just recently that I found out about the EFi-X dongle, a device that plugs into compatible motherboards and allows them to boot a wide range of operating systems including OSX.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't realise the dongle had the boot manager apart of it - I read that as the dongle allowed OSX to boot by fooling the software into thinking it was compatible hardware.